# warning: implicit declaration of function 'daemon'

Tags: c, daemon, unistd.h, implicit-declaration

I get this warning while compiling my program. daemon() is declared in unistd.h and its included. How to fix this or make it disappear?

error:

```
dcron.c: In function 'main':
dcron.c:35:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'daemon' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if (daemon(1, 0) != 0) {
    ^
```

part of program:

```
if (daemon(1, 0) != 0) {
   fprintf(stderr, "error: failed to daemonize\n");
   syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "error: failed to daemonize");
   return 1;
}
```

setup:
gcc4.8.2, glibc2.19
CFLAGS=-std=c99 -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra

Comment: What OS is this? The daemon() function is in that header on Linux, but it is not a POSIX function, and won't necessarily be there on other operating systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux [`daemon()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) is made available by `#define`ing either

- `_XOPEN_SOURCE`
- `_BSD_SOURCE`

by doing

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
```

or

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
```

before `#include`ing

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

or by adding `-D _XOPEN_SOURCE` or `-D _BSD_SOURCE` to the compilation command.

Comment: Thanks. On my system it was #define __USE_BSD

Comment: Do **not** set double-underscored-prefixed defines directly. They are for internal use only! Setting them from your source might lead to unexpected results. Use `_BSD_SOURCE` to have __USE_BSD` defined.

Comment: Nowadays (gcc 9.3.0), when _BSD_SOURCE is deprecated, we can use _DEFAULT_SOURCE.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the relevant header file and enable the `_BSD_SOURCE` feature test macro:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
```

From `man 3 daemon`:

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> daemon(): _BSD_SOURCE || (_XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE < 500)